# c function: re-initialize a static array or declare new every call?

Tags: c, arrays, static

I wonder what is the best way if I want to use an zero-initialized array of n unsigned char elements within a function. n is approx. 600.

a) Newly declare the array at every function call:

```
unsigned char buffer[n] = {0};
```

b) Declare as static but memset every function call:

```
static unsigned char buffer[n] = {0};
memset (buffer, 0, n);
```

I would expect that memset and initializing in (a) would cost the same. But for (a) I need to allocate memory every funktion call and free it when I leave the function. This would not happen in (b) because the array is declared to be static.
Am I right?

Comment: Considering that all modern compiler put local variables on the stack, including arrays, "allocating" such memory is just the compiler adjusting the stack and frame pointer registers appropriately. Which is must do *anyway*. There's no "real" allocation (like calling `malloc` or similar).

Comment: I don't expect any diference [in performance]. Allocating and initializingan automatic array of 600 will probably let the compiler too insert a `memset` call to initialize it (or it could insert the machine instructions).

Comment: The downside of the method with a static array is that it won't be thread safe. Even recursion won't be possible. Hence if you're not fighting for the last microsecond, use the other method. And if you're fighting, test it.

Comment: @Ronald - You may declare it `thread_local`. But yeah, recursion is still impaired. Not to mention there's a performance hit.

Comment: @StoryTeller well, the better term would have been to call it not re-entrant. That's always very dangerous. I had a situation (ages ago) I did a printf() within a signal handler. It crashed every now and then because sometimes the signal handler was invoked during a malloc() call (a debugger doesn't help in such a case). So I learned that making functions re-entrant is member of the set of good ideas

Comment: @Ronald - I'd go further say it's a distinguished member of said set.

Comment: I guess there's a chance for better locality with the local (on-stack) version, since global variables will be on the heap and thus might be "polluting" the caching of the stack. The clearing ought to be the same, I'd guess the compiler would generate a `memset()` call for the local variable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it `static` means that it get zero-initialized at start-up, which does you no good here since you set it to zero in run-time anyway. If the system-specific static initialization is carried out in run-time, this would mean that you get a slower program start-up.

Also, `static` variables are not thread-safe, which may or may not be an issue.

What takes time in the stack allocation case, is not the allocation, but rather the zero-out. So if you are concerned about performance, the best solution is to not zero-initialize it at all, but instead ensure that the algorithm writes to each and every byte of the array. I don't know the algorithm here, but "I must have a local array of all zeroes with the size 600" is a strange requirement.

Comment: good aspect. The array is used to store data I receive over UDP. The length of data can vary between 13 and 525 chars. 600 was just to tell a number. If I get you right following seems to be a better way: receive by UDP data and write it directly to the array. Then zero-out the remaining Bytes. I'll try this. Thanks for inspiration

Comment: @Stefatronik Or just use a size variable to keep a track of how much of the array that is actually used.